# What is "gratricide"?

Tags: meaning

I've been reading Michael Innes books again (in this case "From London Far"), and I came across the word *gratricidal*, in the a passage about a Scottish castle...

> Castle Moila was famous alike in legend, history, and fiction. To
>   these courts Magnus Barelegs has brought fire; Donald, Lord of the
>   Isles, a traitor's promise; Macleod of Lewis a *gratricidal* knife.
>   Here had come Prince Charles Edward, thwarted of a throne, and
>   daughters of a hereditary captain had offered him manchets and wine.

So what is *gratricide*? Attempts to find this online are stymied by the spelling being corrected to *fratricide*.

Comment: Seems either typo for fratricidal or invented...

Comment: ...maybe it was _bratricide_? :-}

Comment: I first thought that 'gratricide' would be killing a grandparent - but, apparently not.

Comment: If you look up [Macleod of Lewis on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clan_MacLeod_of_Lewis) you'll see that they were well known for intra-clan feuds which is well described by the word 'fratricidal'. Therefore it is very likely that it is a typo.

Comment: Just a tip: to search for an exact term in Google, without it automatically showing results for a "fixed" typo, put speech marks around the word. Entering "gratricide" into Google **including the speech marks** returns _this page_ as its top result :)

Comment: Wow, one of the rare cases where spelling correction is actually right. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a typographical error future visitors are unlikely to encounter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Magnus Barelegs, named in the question, was [Magnus Olafsen](https://www.euppublishing.com/doi/abs/10.3366/shr.1994.73.2.216?journalCode=shr) who ruled in the 11th century. Therefore the 'MacLeod of Lewis' mentioned must be contemporary, or perhaps somewhat later.

The Lewis branch of the clan MacLeod, descended from Leod, a son of [Olaf the Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olaf_the_Black), was a notoriously bloodthirsty family, particularly among themselves :

> The traditional progenitor of the Macleods was Leod, whom tradition made a son of Olaf the Black, King of Mann and the Isles. Tradition gave Leod two sons, Tormod - progenitor of the Macleods of Harris and Dunvegan (Sìol Tormoid); and Torquil - progenitor of the Macleods of Lewis (Sìol Torcaill). In the 16th and early seventeenth centuries the chiefly line of the **Clan Macleod of The Lewes was** **extinguished due to family infighting.** **This feuding directly led to the fall of the clan, and loss of its lands** to the Clan Mackenzie. The modern line of chiefs of Clan Macleod of The Lewes are represented by the leading family of a cadet branch of the clan - the Macleods of Raasay.

[ScotWeb](https://www.scotweb.co.uk/info/macleod-of-lewis/)

Thus the reference is almost certainly a misprint for 'fratricide'.

---

Note : As one of the Johnstones of Annan (*Numquam non Paratus* - 'never unprepared') whose ancestors were prone to sneak over the border and raid the English, one can make no criticism of other Scottish clans.

Comment: This explains so much...

Comment: @JamesMcLeod I have edited to highlight that the Lewis branch of the McLeod's all died out.

Comment: Then I suppose my siblings are safe.

Answer (score 5):

Here, ***gratricidal*** is a typographical error (or in short "typo") of the word "***fratricidal***."

Fratricidal according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fratricidal) is

> one that murders or kills his or her own brother or sister or an individual (such as a countryman) having a relationship like that of a brother or sister.

Following [website](http://www.finedictionary.com/fratricide.html)<sub>1</sub> presents all the typographical errors associated with the word ***Fratricidal***.

> dratricide, rratricide, **gratricide**, vratricide, cratricide, featricide, fdatricide, ffatricide, ftatricide, frqtricide, frwtricide, frstricide, frztricide, frarricide, frafricide, fragricide, frayricide, frateicide, fratdicide, fratficide, fratticide, fratrucide, fratrjcide, fratrkcide, fratrocide, fratrixide, fratridide, fratrifide, fratrivide, fratricude, fratricjde, fratrickde, fratricode, fratricise, fratriciee, fratricife, fratricice, fratricixe, fratricise, fratricidw, fratricids, fratricidd, fratricidr

So, *fratricidal knife* is a knife which is used to murder/kill their own siblings or to murder/kill individuals having a relationship like that of a brothers/sisters.

---

<sub>1: scroll down the bottom of the page.</sub>

Comment: \*boggle\* that somebody bothered to create a website of "here are all the typos that you can get from a word by substituting one character for an adjacent one on a QWERTY keyboard."

Answer (score 4):

It's a typo:

> By his MacKenzie wife, Allan [MacLeod] had three sons, one of whom, Alexander, succeeded him. His second wife was a  daughter of Roderick MacLeod of Lewis and bore him a son, Roderick, whose name, to quote Morrison (1968-76. section V) is synonymous with 'soaring ambition, crooked counsels and bloodthirsty deeds'. **Allan's two brothers** who lived in Lewis resented the MacKenzie alliance, **came to Gairloch and murdered Allan** and the two younger boys.
>
> ["THE MACLEODS OF LEWIS AND OF ASSYNT, COIGACH AND GAIRLOCH"](https://ssns.org.uk/resources/Documents/Books/NWRoss_1994/09_Halford-Macleod_NWRoss_1994_pp_193-213.pdf)